# Zeacom UC Compared To Microsoft UC

Tags: unified-communications

Which is a better solution? Zeacom's Unified Communications or Microsoft's Unified Communications (UC)? Which one has your company implemented? I heard Microsoft coined the term "Unified Communications" but they were slow to jumpstart it... Other companies such as Zeacom have been working on and improving on their UC product since years ago. But Microsoft is such a standard. Which one would you go with?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft.  I have not heard of zeacom but even if it's a better product I'd suspect that you'll find it far easier to support microsofts UC, from a pure support and from an ecosystem point of view.